# Emacs Helm: what actions can I do in a helm buffer?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs, emacs-helm

I have 2 questions:

- In a helm buffer like `helm mini` or `helm ag`, there are usually too much candidates. In `evil` mode I can use `C-d` or `C-u` to scroll down or up. Can I do such things in helm buffer?
- Sometimes when I enter a file path/name, there is only a default one in the buffer but not the one I entered. Whenever I hit `enter` the default path/file will be visit. What actions can I do in the input bar (where you input characters)?

Would you please provide the document describing these kind of keymaps? I can't find them because I don't what's my question :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using spacemacs, try <kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-keymap` `helm-map`, it's bound to `SPC h d K`.

Sadly emacs itself doesn't have such a nice `describe-keymap` function. In this case you may either:

- copy `describe-keymap` from spacemacs
- use `describe-bindings` (it's not so smooth to read and misses some keymaps)
- <kbd>C-h v</kbd> `helm-map` to browse the keymap as a variable (hard to read because the keys are in the form of something like unicode code points, but if you config all your key bindings yourself without framework-defaults, this is fine for "what's my bindings?" and debugging)

Comment: OMG thanks again lol. But would you please tell me how can I find out which bindings are for mini-buffer?

Comment: @spacegoing I'm a newbee myself but luckily: `C-h v` `minibuffer-local-map`(found this variable thanks to helm) shows a few bindings(probably added by spacemacs) and ``minibuffer-local-map is a variable defined in `keymap.c'.`` So common emacs shortcuts should apply here cause it's defined by emacs. Minibuffer itself has some special keys, [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minibuffer-Edit.html#Minibuffer-Edit). I tried `(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "C-w") #'backward-kill-word)` and it works so you may remap keys in mini buffer like this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `describe-bindings` or [helm-descbinds](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm-descbinds) to find the currently active bindings. The latter allows you to interactively search them through helm.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However when I try to execute the command it says that `Error: Trying to run helm within a helm session`. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: This may be because spacemacs runs helm as default and includes helm-descbinds bound to SPC ? Try clicking in your main buffer, esc, and SPC ?